# How to use the camera calibration in opencv to measure real world coordinates from pixels

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, camera, camera-calibration

I already have read 3 books form the topic

- Practical OpenCV - Smarth Brahmbhat
- Learning OpenCV - O'Reilly
- OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programing Cookbook - Robert Laganière

I already do the calibration processes and I have the all the return parameters after calibration, like:

- Camera Matrix
- Distortion coefficients
- Extrinsic parameters

I ran a program to take this data. This program is in the OpenCV tutorials, in the section "calib3d module. Camera calibration and 3D reconstruction"

I am going to describe the process, I put a fixed camera looking for the floor and the chessboard in front of the camera. I took 15 pictures of the chessboard moving it and the last picture the chessboard is on the floor with inclination 0º.

A several books talk to use this formula to convert real word coordinates to pixels.

[Formula to get pixels from real word coordinates](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o77drhopfqgqju6/Captura%20de%20pantalla%20de%202015-03-09%2010%3A44%3A52.png?dl=0)https://www.dropbox.com/s/o77drhopfqgqju6/Captura%20de%20pantalla%20de%202015-03-09%2010%3A44%3A52.png

The translation and rotation matrix is 3 rows x 4 cols but the extrinsic parameters are 15 rows x 6 cols, one per picture taken. I use the last one row. I have read and have found that the 3 first cols correspond to the rotations coefficients and the last 3 cols to translation coefficients but the rotation matrix are 3x3 so I use the function **cv::Rodrigues** to convert it to 3x3 and I put it with a col next to returned cv::Mat from cv::Rodrigues (I read this from **Learning OpenCV - O'Reilly**).

So, I need pixels to real world coordinates, not backward. So I applied the Cramer Rule to get X and Y, but its return me with out sense points, like 0,0 pixels are -4,-3 in real world.

I am asking how to get real world coordinates from pixels in the right way. I hope have been clear

Comment: one pixel corresponds to a whole ray of object points. so you can compute the object point in dependence of the ray-length. if you have multiple pixel (=rays) corresponding to the same object point you can compute the intersection of those rays. if you know that the point lies on a specific object with known position&geometry (e.g. a plane/chessboard) you can compute the point where the ray intersects the object